# Compare contents of variable against contents of another variable - jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter, contains

I'm creating a page search function and I need to compare the contents of one variable to see if it exists in another variable in an if statement.

To make it simple here's an expample:

```
var name = 'james';
var place = 'james lives in europe';

if (place:contains(james)) {
   ....... do something
}
```

Anyone know how to do this with jquery. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (place.indexOf(name ) >=0) {
  // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a regexp :

```
var str="james lives in europe";
var reg1=new RegExp("[james]","g");
if (str.match(reg1)) {
  document.write("'[james]' is in str");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript -

```
if (place.indexOf(name) != -1) {
   alert('do something');
}
```